# Añadir opciones a elemento SELECT desde un arreglo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, array

**EDIT**

Pues lo del titulo, realizo una petición al servidor con ajax, y me regresa un arreglo, donde como pueden observar se guarda todo lo de la tabla paises

> $sql = "select idPais, nombre from paises";

Esta es la función que utilizo para traerme los datos de la BD.

```html
   public function cargarPaises(){
  $modelo = new Conexion();
  $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
  $sql = "select idPais, nombre from paises";
  $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();   
  return $statement;
 }
```

Luego acá mando a llamar a la función mencionada arriba

> Lo que se ve comentareado era para verificar que me trajiera correctamente los datos de la BD 
> {"idPais":"1","nombre":"Mexico"}{"idPais":"3","nombre":"Albania"}{"idPais":"4","nombre":"Alemania"}{"idPais":"5","nombre":"Andorra"}{"idPais":"6","nombre":"Angola"}{"idPais":"7","nombre":"Antigua y barbuda"}{"idPais":"8","nombre":"Antillas holandesas"}{"idPais":"10","nombre":"Argelia"}
>   
> El cual me trae correctamente los registros de mi base de datos con
>   echo json_encode($result);
>   OJO: me los regresa sin los [ ].

```html
<?php

require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

$consultas = new Consultas();
$datos = $consultas->cargarPaises();

if (count($datos) > 0) {  
 while ($result = $datos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $result["idPais"], $result["nombre"]);echo"<br>";
  //return $result;
  //$nombre=$result['nombre'];
  //$idPais=$result['idPais'];
  //echo "<option value=".$idPais.">".$nombre."</option>\n";
  echo json_encode($result);  
 }         
}else{
 return "No hay opciones en la BD";
}

?>
```

> Lo que se ve comentado "echo count($datos)" era para ver que si contiene todos los registros de la BD

Y esto es el codigo JQUERY donde quiero recorrer el json que contiene toda la informacion, e ir añadiendolo como una opcion a mi elemento select html

```js
   $('#email').click(function(event) {
 $.get('Controlador/cargarPaises.php', function(data) {
  //AQUI
 });
});
```

Mas sin embargo, estos no consigo anexarlos al elemento SELECT, por su atención y ayuda gracias.

Comment: Estás intentando coger datos de una variable PHP con javascript, tendrás que pasarlos a javascript.

Comment: intente pasarlos a json para luego leerlos con javascript mas sin embargo no logro que funcione correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de intentar varios métodos para realizar lo deseado (Llenar un elemento SELECT de HTML desde un arreglo generado por una consulta a una BD). Aquí les dejo el código para si alguien le sirve para futuras referencias.

Esta es mi funcion que se encuentra en un archivo php donde pongo todas las consultas que realizaré a mi BD.

```html
public function cargarPaises(){
   $modelo = new Conexion();
   $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
   $sql = "select idPais, nombre from paises";
   $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute();   
   return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
  }
```

Luego en otro archivo php donde mando a llamar a mi función, guardo lo que me regresa utilizando json_encode

```html
<?php

 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

 $consultas = new Consultas();
 $datos = $consultas->cargarPaises();

 $results = (count($datos) > 0) ? $datos : array("error"=>"No hay opciones en la BD");
 $arrayJson = json_encode($results);
 print_r($arrayJson);

?>
```

> $results = (count($datos) > 0) ? $datos : array("error"=>"No hay opciones en la BD");
>  Esto lo interpreto como si se tratase de un if resumido?, es la unica linea que no me queda clara.

Y ya con este ultimo codigo en mi archivo javascript populo mi SELECT

```js
$('#email').click(function(event) {
  $.get('Controlador/cargarPaises.php', function(data) { 
  console.log("entre");  
     $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
      console.log("estoy recorriendo");
      //console.log(data);
      $('#comboboxPais').append('<option value="' + opt.idPais + '">' + opt.nombre + '</option>');
     });
 }, 'json');
 });
```

Espero le sirva a alguien mas de referencia.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la consulta devuelve un campo Id y uno Descripcion para los países

```
$('#email').click(function(event) {         
     var combo = $('#comboboxPais');
     $.get("Controlador/cargarPaises.php", function(data, status){              
         $.each(data, function(index, value) {
             combo.append( $('<option></option>').val(value.Id).html(value.Descripcion));
         });
       }
    });
});
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta intente el metodo que me mencionas obviamente cambiando los nombres "Id" y "Descripcion" por los nombres de las columnas en mi BD que seria idPais y nombre, mas sin embargo, no me añade nada al select

Comment: @antonio291093 que error te tira? en la consola de google chrome

Comment: No me tira ningun error, simplemente no carga nada en el select

Comment: @antonio291093 pone un alert('') dentro del get antes del each para ver si llega a entrar.

Comment: Sip, si entra, puse uno antes de entrar y otro dentro

Comment: puse tambien un alert adentro del each que dice "estoy recorriendo el array", simplemente para ver que lo muestre, pero no despliega el alert.

Comment: nunca va a entrar al each ya que data no devuelve ningun dato. La url es la correcta?

Comment: Si, y si me devuelve las 427 filas que tengo en la BD, con echo count($datos) verifique que si trajiera los datos

Comment: @antonio291093 no soy experto en php pero si en vez de return $datos utilizas echo $datos, ya que no veo error en el codigo javascript. echo se utiiliza para dar salida de valores y return para devolver valores desde una funcion, que ahi no veo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto a ver si ves los datos:

```
$.get('Controlador/cargarPaises.php')
      .done(function( data ) {
         var content = JSON.parse(data);
         console.log(content);
         alert(content.idPais);
      });
```

De todos modos yo suelo hacer esto mediante ajax (en el onclick en lugar del get) y cargo html, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "Controlador/cargarPaises.php",
        //data:"id="+id ,
        success: function(html){
            $("#response").html(data);
        }
    });
```

En la página donde haces click creas un div que es donde vas a poner tu código html:

```
<div id="response"></div>
```

Y en la página destino imprimes el código que vas a mostrar dentro, en tu caso el select con sus options en html a partir de las variables PHP.

**cargarPaises.php**

```
<select name="paises">
  <option> ... //crear opciones con bucle en función de tus resultados
</select>
```

Con esto evitas tener que pasar las variables a javascript, ya que sólo lo necesitabas para crear las opciones.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, probé el codigo para verificar que me trajiera los datos, pero me suelta lo siguiente en la consola del navegador
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 32
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:47:29)
    at i (<anonymous>:2:28017)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (<anonymous>:2:28783)
    at A (<anonymous>:4:14035)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:4:16323)

Comment: Prueba a hacerlo por ajax, lo que he puesto a partir del segundo párrafo de código, yo suelo usarlo y va muy bien.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo solucioné, el problema era que traia demasiados registros de mi BD, y por lo tanto json_encode() no los cargaba, pero ya quedo funcional, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y la de los demas :)